# Html form pass input checkbox variable without dots

Tags: php, html, forms

I have wired problem.

I have this input inside my form

```
<form action="..." method="post">
    <div class="radio">
      <input class="check-with-label" type="checkbox" id="c1-img0" name="img;http://img01.cp.aliimg.com/bao/uploaded/i1/1610868057/T25iVOXaNeXXXXXXXX_!!1610868057.jpg">
      <label class="label-for-check" for="c1-img0"><img src="http://img01.cp.aliimg.com/bao/uploaded/i1/1610868057/T25iVOXaNeXXXXXXXX_!!1610868057.jpg"></label>
     </div>
</form>
```

But in my php file i get this variable when i call `print_r($_POST);`

```
[img;http://img01_cp_aliimg_com/bao/uploaded/i1/1610868057/T25iVOXaNeXXXXXXXX_!!1610868057_jpg] => on
```

Like you see I lose all dots in my link in PHP file.

```
Orginal: img;http://img01.cp.aliimg.com/bao/uploaded/i1/1610868057/T25iVOXaNeXXXXXXXX_!!1610868057.jpg
Recived: img;http://img01_cp_aliimg_com/bao/uploaded/i1/1610868057/T25iVOXaNeXXXXXXXX_!!1610868057_jpg
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? that name attribute's totally invalid.

Comment: I wanna pass images url to PHP file. I have page when I can chose images to pass with checkbox.

Comment: Change `action="..."` to `action=""` and try.

Comment: Change `img;http://img01....` to `value` and add `name="img_name"` to checkbox. Then you can get that value with `$_POST['img_name']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put image link in `name` attribute instead of `value`.

Try

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="radio">
      <input class="check-with-label" type="checkbox" id="c1-img0" name="image" value="img;http://img01.cp.aliimg.com/bao/uploaded/i1/1610868057/T25iVOXaNeXXXXXXXX_!!1610868057.jpg">
      <label class="label-for-check" for="c1-img0"><img src="http://img01.cp.aliimg.com/bao/uploaded/i1/1610868057/T25iVOXaNeXXXXXXXX_!!1610868057.jpg"></label>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```